# Can an Android app installed in /system/app folder access privileged ports?

Tags: android, android-networking

Is an app installed in the /system/app folder automatically qualified as a system app with all the privileges (to be honest, I am not sure what all the privileges are).

I installed an app in /system/app, but it still gets the same error:

```
 exception:bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The code that generates the exception is:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(67);
```

Port 67 (<1024) is apparently a privileged port that ordinary apps are not allowed to access.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: As with any *nix-style OS, you have to run with superuser privileges (e.g., root) to open ports below 1024. Simply being installed in `/system/app` does not change your Linux UID to be one with superuser privileges.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the tip.  I used ES File Explorer to check the properties of the app.  It shows Owner: root, Group: root.  Does this mean it will run as root? If not, how can I run the app as root?

Comment: "Does this mean it will run as root?" -- AFAIK, no. "If not, how can I run the app as root?" -- AFAIK, you don't. I am no expert on root apps on Android, but my understanding is that the *app* does not run as root, but rather it can fork other processes using `su`/`sudo`-style stuff to have them run as root, possibly involving user permission.

Comment: The ADB shell shows root@android:/ #.  I started the app by using command: am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName, and it makes no difference.  Is there a way to start an app as root with an ADB shell command?